# Multi Dex issue with Google AdMobs and Firebase analytics in Android

Tags: android, firebase, admob, android-multidex

I am working on Android application where I am integrating Firebase Analytics and Google AdMobs. I am getting Multi Dex issue if I am using both together, independently both are working if I am not using other one Gradle link. I have used many solutions available on this platform, but nothing works for me.

I am putting my Gradle files along with the error which I am getting on compile time.

App Level Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fxxxxxipes"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    compile project(':simplecropimagelib_')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'cn.ziyeyouhu.android:sweet-alert-dialog:1.0'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    compile fileTree(include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

}
```

Project Level Gradle File:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
//        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error which I am getting on Console:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Solution which I am currently using to fix this issue but still error is coming, I am using it in my Application Class:

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me,

multiDex problem is always version conflict problem.
So in my opinion, don't need to install MultiDex and just try to keep same version of every gradles.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem thats why want to share for others. It was giving me a Dex file issue because for Analytics I was using Firebase and for Admobs I was using Google Libraries. Same features & functionality of Admobs is also available in firebase and integrated also. So now I am using now Firebase libraries only and it is now not giving any Dex issue:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```